# Plotly: Remove legend title using template

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

Even after passing `'title':None` inside `layout.legend` in the template, the chart still shows a legend title, whereas it should change the default setting to no legend title.[image: passed in template]

If I manually pass it though with `fig.update_layout()`, it then removes the title.

[image: passed separately]

Why is this happening and how do I change the default setting to no legend title?

Here's the code to recreate the graph (The manual passing in `update.layout()` is commented out)-

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

pio.templates['my_theme'] = go.layout.Template({
    'layout': {'annotationdefaults': {'arrowcolor': '#2a3f5f', 'arrowhead': 0, 'arrowwidth': 1},
               'autotypenumbers': 'strict',
               'coloraxis': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}},
               'colorscale': {'diverging': [[0, '#8e0152'], [0.1, '#c51b7d'],
                                            [0.2, '#de77ae'], [0.3, '#f1b6da'],
                                            [0.4, '#fde0ef'], [0.5, '#f7f7f7'],
                                            [0.6, '#e6f5d0'], [0.7, '#b8e186'],
                                            [0.8, '#7fbc41'], [0.9, '#4d9221'], [1,
                                            '#276419']],
                              'sequential': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                             [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                             [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                             [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                             [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                             [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                             [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                             [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                             [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0,
                                             '#f0f921']],
                              'sequentialminus': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                                  [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                                  [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                                  [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                                  [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                                  [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                                  [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                                  [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                                  [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'],
                                                  [1.0, '#f0f921']]},
               'colorway': ["#db2b39","#3d405b","#2fbf71","#faa613","#00a6fb"],
               'font': {'color': '#2a3f5f'},
               'geo': {'bgcolor': 'white',
                       'lakecolor': 'white',
                       'landcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                       'showlakes': True,
                       'showland': True,
                       'subunitcolor': 'white'},
               'hoverlabel': {'align': 'left'},
               'hovermode': 'closest',
               'legend': {'orientation': 'v',
                          'bordercolor': '#000000',
                          'borderwidth': 0.7,
                          'itemwidth': 30,
                          'x': 0.01,
                          'y': 1.075,
                          'title': None,
                          'bgcolor':'#F6F5F4'},
               'mapbox': {'style': 'light'},
               'paper_bgcolor': 'white',
               'plot_bgcolor': 'white',
               'polar': {'angularaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''},
                         'bgcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                         'radialaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}},
               'scene': {'xaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': 'white'},
                         'yaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': 'white'},
                         'zaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': 'white'}},
               'separators':'.',
               'shapedefaults': {'line': {'color': '#2a3f5f'}},
               'ternary': {'aaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''},
                           'baxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''},
                           'bgcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                           'caxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}},
               'title': {'x': 0.5,
                        'font_size':30},
               'xaxis': {'automargin': True,
                         'gridcolor': '#eeeeee',
                         'linecolor': 'white',
                         'ticks': '',
                         'title': {'standoff': 15},
                         'zerolinecolor': 'white',
                         'zerolinewidth': 2},
               'yaxis': {'automargin': True,
                         'gridcolor': '#eeeeee',
                         'linecolor': 'white',
                         'ticks': '',
                         'title': {'standoff': 15},
                         'zerolinecolor': 'white',
                         'zerolinewidth': 2}}
})

pio.templates.default = 'my_theme'

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {27: '2020-01-28',
  28: '2020-01-29',
  29: '2020-01-30',
  30: '2020-01-31',
  31: '2020-02-01'},
 'new_cases': {27: 2651.0, 28: 589.0, 29: 2068.0, 30: 1692.0, 31: 2111.0},
 'new_cases_smoothed': {27: 717.286,
  28: 801.429,
  29: 1082.857,
  30: 1283.714,
  31: 1515.0}})

fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=['new_cases','new_cases_smoothed'],title='New cases',
              color_discrete_sequence = ['#DB2B39','#0D0628'])
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')#, legend=dict(title=None))
fig.show()
```

Comment: I copy and pasted the code you provided on a fresh google colab and it doesn't run.
It says `ValueError: Invalid properties specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.Legend: ('itemwidth', 'title')`
for line 102. It's this line: `'zerolinewidth': 2}}`.

 Could you correct that so we can help you with the legend question?

Comment: @KarenPalacio I am unable to recreate the error you're facing. It works fine for me. Maybe check your plotly version? Mine is `4.14.3`

Answer (score 5):

This works

```
fig.update_layout(title_text='ALPACA Queries',
    title_x=0.5, showlegend=True,
    legend_title=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was certain that the following would do the trick:

```
'title': {'text': None}
```

But to my surprise, the text `'variable'` still pops up. An empty string `''` doesn't work, and neither does `'title': {'text': False}`.

And I find this very interesting, since you're able to edit all other attributes of the legend title *except* the title text itself. Like color, for example, with:

```
'title': {'font': {'color':'blue'}}
```

[image]

And this opens up for a sub-optimal solution with:

```
'title': {'font': {'color':''rgba(0,0,0,0'}}
```

Which gives you:

[image]

But this arguably looks a bit weird since you've still got the extra space for the text.
So this seems to be a bug of some kind.

Comment: haha it does look weird with the empty space. I think I'll just resort to manually passing it to each graph until an optimal solution is found.

Comment: Just found this bug also exists for axis titles defined inside the template. All other properties of the axes work fine, just not the title.

Comment: If my template defines `'xaxis': {'title': {'text': "ayy"}}`, and then I pass `fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(title=None))` or `fig.update_xaxes(title=None)` along with the graph call. Then, it displays the `xaxis` `title` as "ayy".



Found this interesting. Seems template property is overridden by graph call and only when you set graph call to `None` does it reveal the template property hiding underneath.

Answer (score 2):

I am using "plotly-express" and version is "4.14.3".

Here's what has worked for me to actually remove the title:

```
from plotly import express as px

# make your plot
fig = px.scatter(...)

# udpate the legend's title by setting it to none
fig.update_layout(legend={'title_text':''})
## fig.update_layout({'legend_title_text': ''}) worked too.

# display it
fig.show()
```

Comment: Yes, well the question was about how to remove it by permanently via a pre-defined template.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me with `plotly.graph_objects`, `go.Figure` and `plotly==5.5.0`

```
fig.update_layout(
    title="Performance Results",
    legend_title="",
    ...,
)
```

Comment: I am aware of this method, it's mentioned in the question itself. I was looking for a way to change the default setting in the template, not to pass it to each figure.